# Scifi novel where people can use golems to be in multiple places at the same time

Tags: story-identification

Trying to remember a scifi novel set in the future where you can load your personality into a "golem" and later download its experiences so you get all the memories. So your real body can go to the gym for exercise, and you can send golems to the library to study, and get more done in the same time. I think the plot was about a detective investigating a murder.

I am pretty sure the word "golem" was used to describe the copy things but not entirely.

I didn't actually read this novel, just read a description of it...

I think it was published somewhere in 2000-2010.

Answer (score 56, accepted):

The book is [Kiln People](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kiln_People) by David Brin.

> The novel takes place in a future in which people can create clay duplicates (called "dittos" or golems) of themselves. A ditto retains all of the archetype's memories up until the time of duplication. The duplicate lasts only about a day, and the original person (referred to in the book as an archie, from "archetype", or "rig", from "original") can then choose whether or not to upload the ditto's memories. Most dittos want to inload, so that their experience will be continuous with that of their archie. Most people use dittos to do their work, as they are affordable even for the poor.

Was able to find this by going through a list of Hugo winners/nominees.

Comment: Was it a winner or nominee?

Comment: [Nominee](http://www.worldswithoutend.com/books_year_index.asp?year=2003) for four awards, missed out on all of them. Superb book. One of the few I've read that's properly addressed the identity aspect of cloning and offered a solution. Of sorts.